# Average incorrect : decimal point always .0

Tags: java, arrays, int, double, average

I'm pretty new to arrays and am trying to create a simple program that calculates the average of 5 numbers. However, when the average is calculated, it always has a decimal point of 0 rather than what it should be, but I'm not sure why..
For example, if I type in 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, it displays 3.0 as the average rather than 3.8. Please help!

```
        int[] boxes = new int[5];

        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter number " + i + " > ");
            int n = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());

            boxes[i-1] = n;
        }

        double mean = ( boxes[0] + boxes[1] + boxes[2] + boxes[3] + boxes[4] ) / 5;

        System.out.println("The average of those five numbers is: " + mean);
```

Thank you!! :)

Comment: Why do you use `int n = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());` instead of  `int n=kb.nextInt();` it's very simple

Answer (score 1):

it is because the operation is done with integers , change your 5 to 5.0

Comment: hehe, you've beaten me by a few seconds :-)

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer you the specifics but there is a huge topic in java called type casting. I reckon, you read it. This is a good puzzle for you to solve yourself. Reminds me of my past :)

Comment: Thanks, Ill look into it :)

Answer (score 0):

**Fast fix**: change `5 -> 5.0D`.

Why? Let's look at dividing process more detail:

1. You get sum from all numbers: `( boxes[0] + boxes[1] + boxes[2] + boxes[3] + boxes[4] )`, result -> `int`.
2. You divide `sum(int type) / 5(int type)` = result also `int type` 3.8 -> 3.
3. Last one its autocast `int -> double`.

That's why you get what you see.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1** :
- You can use 5.0 instead of 5 to have a double division.like that:

```
 double mean = ( boxes[0] + boxes[1] + boxes[2] + boxes[3] + boxes[4] ) / 5.0;
```

**Solution 2** :
- You can use a double cast of your sum like that:

```
 double mean = (double)( boxes[0] + boxes[1] + boxes[2] + boxes[3] + boxes[4] ) / 5;
```

**To improve your answer:**

- You can use `int n=kb.nextInt();` instead of `int n = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());`
- You can count the sum in `for` loop like that:

  ```
  int[] boxes = new int[5];
  int sum=0;
  for (int i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++)
  {
  System.out.print("Enter number " + i + " > ");
  int n=kb.nextInt();
  boxes[i-1] = n;
  sum +=boxes[i-1];
  }

  double mean = sum / 5.0;
  System.out.println("The average of those five numbers is: " + mean);
  ```